# Why is cycles rendering an object out of place?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, displacement

The problem is that when I render my image, this happens:

[image: after being rendered]

Those planes should be touching the walls.

[image]
This is what it looks like in viewport.

[image]

Comment: "Should be" is very vague. Cycles cannot move objects, it's just rendering, so the rendering itself isn't the problem supposedly. To me the walls look like they are angled  away, so to solve this mystery it would be useful to see how it looks in viewport before rendering, or maybe upload the file to check if there is any displacement, shape keys, keyframes or whatever that position the walls like that.

Comment: I haven't set any keyframes so that couldn't be the problem.

Comment: Just taking one possibility of the few (out of many) I've listed, doesn't clarify anything or gives enough information to narrow down your problem. All in all the geometry in the viewport looks a lot different. Would it be possible to upload your file here and paste the generated link in your question: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: I don't know for sure without your blend file but to me it looks like there are 2 planes added and not your objects moved... are you sure there are no hidden objects that are still visible in final render but not in viewport? Your file could help answer this faster

Comment: How do I upload my file??

Comment: @DarkDragon Go to the link I've given in my comment. Follow the instructions there. You have to enter the link to this question, upload the file and then a link to the file is generated which you can post in your question when you edit it.

Comment: The file:  [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=l1OW48mz" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/l1OW48mz/)

Comment: You file is woking correctly for me